# cannot deploy c# app with entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

i have finished a desktop c# project in which i make use of Entity framework 5 and SQL server 2008
in my machine it's working well, but i created a virtual machine and tried to deploy it there and I have problems.

I get this error : **System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.**

I used installshield for the setup and I have installed sql express in the visrual machine, during the setup I create the database and all the tables.

my connection string is this :`name="BussinessContainer" connectionString="metadata=.\Bussiness.csdl|.\Bussiness.ssdl|.\Bussiness.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=yingyangDB;User ID=username;Password=password;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"`

Should I change the connection string?
I searched a lot before posting this, but nothing worked..any help?

Comment: You have `localhost` in your connection!! Also have a look at [Fix : Error : 40 – could not open a connection to SQL server](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/23/sql-server-fix-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Express (normally) doesn't create as a "Default instance" - i.e. connecting by `localhost` isn't sufficient to connect to the local SQL express instance.

You may need to use `localhost\SQLExpress` to connect to the local SQL Express instance (the instance name *may* be different, but usually it is not.

Additionally, you specify an `Initial Catalog` in your connection string, which I assume is pointing at your new DB. However you say that you create the DB during the installation - so that DB may not actually exist in your Instance yet. That may be causing it to fail out. Try taking it out of the string and see if that lets you connect.

Comment: if I change the connection string to `data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS` and try to rebuild my project, it not running it throws the same exception as I said in my question..

Comment: Can you connect to the SQL instance using SQL Management studio express?

Comment: no with localhost\SQLEXPRESS as server name I cant connect, but with localhost I can...

Comment: Strange. Normally it creates as \SQLExpress - although there may be an option to override that during installation. You've set a `Initial Catalog` in your connection string, Does that DB exist yet?

Comment: ah, I misread the original post. I thought you were getting this exception during *installation* (i.e. when you were creating the DB) - not while running the application.